# Read emails from pop account

Tags: outlook, gmail

I  am trying  to read my Gmail messages from a client or device that supports POP, like Microsoft Outlook, so I tried to do that, and I used standard configuration instructions, but when I tried to test Account Settings it shows me an error that test message can not be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specify the right settings? https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960#ts=1665119

This is not a programming question.

Comment: Yes, I did everything as said, but  nothing, so I tried Thunderbird, and all works normal. Thanks.

Comment: I am accessing my Gmail account from Outlook with no problem at all. Are you sure you specified the right SMTP port (465) and SSL encryption? As well as "My outgoing server requires authentication"?

Comment: Yes I did everything as said in tutorial, then I tried with a different account but all the same.